# CsvToBean parse csv file java

Tags: opencsv

```
public static <T> List<T> getCsvData(String file, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
    try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(file)) {
        HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<T> strategy = new HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<>();
        strategy.setType(clazz);

        CsvToBean<T> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder<T>(fr)
                .withSeparator(';')
                .withQuoteChar('\'')
                .withIgnoreQuotations(true)
                .withMappingStrategy(strategy).build();
        return csvToBean.parse();
    }
}
```

I use CsvToBean to convert a csv file into a bean. The csv file uses a semicolon as a separator. When a column value in the file contains a semicolon, it will fail to parse. Is there any way to solve it?

elample   'aa;a';'bbb';